# How get post variable's values on an angular 5 url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am creating an eCommerce website into Angular 5 (front-end) and Laravel 5 (back-end).

I have implemented sagepay payment gateway. When i use sagepay, we redirect customer to sagepay server and after payment sagepay return customer to our website url.

That returning url is an angular 5 url. And sagepay return some value via post method on that returning url. But when we come to our returning url via post method with sagepay post variables then it give error and display **"Cannot POST /our_website_angular_url.html"**

*please let me know how i can get returning variable's values from sagepay to our angular 5 url?*

Thanks

Comment: Angular is client side only. You need to set up a callback url on your webserver, which will hande the post and then redirect to a page with yuur angular app

Comment: Thanks David,
we already doing this as you told that i have created an url in laravel but i want to know that is it good way?
because if any other payment gateway i added into site and if that will not return our system generated unique code like order id then on laravel url how we know that, this transaction is for which order id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when an HTTP request comes from an external site, you have to use a server-side component to handle it like response.php page.

Comment: Yes, i am working in this way. I am creating a route in laravel and will get response on that url after i will redirect customer to angular url.