# Angular 5: get post values similar to $_REQUEST in PHP

Tags: angular

In PHP, we can get post values through `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`. I want to catch post values (post values are throwing by an external site) in Angular 6.

I read the post [How get post variable's values on an angular 5 url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449923/how-get-post-variables-values-on-an-angular-5-url) however, unable to understand. Note, I'm using Laravel as back-end to provide APIs to Angular.

Can someone please explain me how to get post values in Angular with examples/codes ?

Below is the Process Flow:

Third party website provide us some POST values in a Angular URL. We have to consume these POST values within Angular and process accordingly.

Comment: Can you add more info? Are the POST values from a request you sent? What is the specific flow?

Comment: @yazantahhan I've edited my question with the process flow, please check and response.